# Visualizing GLDAS data using GGE

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation

When I try to visualize any GLDAS data, it seems to be all black? I've tried adjusting visualization parameters with no success.

Very short code snippet below:

```js
var Daily = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H")
                               //.select('Rainf_tavg');
                               .select('Rainf_f_tavg');
print(Daily.first());
Map.addLayer(Daily.first());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this dataset, but with a little bit of exploring, it seems that this image has a value that is in fact zero in large parts of the world, and where it is nonzero it is generally in the form of clusters of circular patches.

But perhaps more importantly, nearly all of the values are less than 0.001, so you need to set `max` that low to see much. Here's visualization parameters that will at least show most of the areas where the dataset has nonzero data, at the price of being clipped to white many places:

```js
var Daily = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H")
    .select('Rainf_f_tavg');
Map.addLayer(Daily.first(), {min: 0, max: 0.00001});
```

In this sort of situation, where values vary widely around the world, you need to choose visualization parameters that are most helpful for your specific region of interest, not just the dataset as a whole. There's too much dynamic range.

[image: Map of the world with this script]

Comment: Thank you! I am using a smaller region but wanted to simplify just to ask about this type of issue. Thanks again